# flutter build web didn't work (Missing index.html.) in flutter 2

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-build

[image]

I can't get a web release from my flutter app

when I use `flutter build web` I see this Error :  Missing index.html

Then I run the `flutter create` but I facing by this Error : No option specified for the output of directory. Create a new flutter project.

However the my project is a new project and I have not made any changes to it

Comment: Please post your current code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: command : flutter create

Comment: I use from flutter create but I see some errors you can see theme in picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot the last point  "."  of `flutter create`

`flutter create`  is false
`flutter create .` is true